# How do I invert an integer around a selected number point

Tags: matlab, function, euclidean-distance, inversion, symmetry

I want to essentially be able to have a function `swap` where I can enter 2 arguments. The first would be the central point, the point of inversion so to speak, while the second would be the number I want to find the opposite of, with respect to the point.

So if I put in `swap(5,2)` it would return `8`. 

The idea being that `5-2=3` then `5+3=8`.

Answer (score 2):

Just write it down on paper:

```
function out = swap(in1,in2)
% pivot = in1 - in2;
% out = in1 + pivot = in1 + (in1 - in2) = 2*in1 - in2
out = 2*in1 - in2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional form (in its own `.m` file or another function file)

```
function out = swap(x, y)
    out = x + (x-y);
end

% Then in another file / command window
swap(5,2) % >> 8
```

Anonymous function (can be defined anywhere within the scope it is used)

```
swap = @(x,y) x + (x-y);
% Then in same function / script
swap(5,2) % >> 8
```